# Can a Micro handle torrent downloading?

Tags: microcontroller, usb

Is it possible to design a circuit that have an LCD, a USB port and a LAN port and be able to get torrent files from a flash drive and download them to the flash drive?
I saw a direct URL file downloader circuit using PIC before but I can find it.
Do you know something like that for torrents?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, its possible, you even mentioned you've seen something like it before.  This is quite a generic question.

Comment: @KrisBahnsen: The thing I saw was a direct link downloader. but the torrent protocol is more complex. after that do you know a designed one?

Comment: do you plan to make a stealth torrent downloader? like a usb-key with an ethernet plug on the other end -- put the .torrent files on there, and stick it into a network connected to the internet somewhere well hidden -- then wait for it to download and grab it later? nice idea :P

Comment: This is a bit of a necrobump, but I liked the idea of this project so much that I'm in the process of attempting it. Once it's complete, I'll drop a link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish most/all of this using an [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) with an [ethernet shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet), or the special [Arduino Ethernet](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet) board. The newer ethernet shields even come with a micro-SD card slot. The [BitTorrent protocol](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification) should be simple enough to run on a small device, though I'd probably invest in one of the more powerful boards (e.g. Mega2560) to be safe. You can read from and write to FAT16 and FAT32 filesystems on standard SD and SDHC cards using the [SD library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SD). They've even been nice enough to provide libraries for [Hitachi HD44780](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal) compatible screens and another for [KS0108](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/GLCDks0108) compatible screens to take care of the display part. There's also a great [SHA1 library for Arduino](http://code.google.com/p/cryptosuite/), which will be necessary for computing info-hashes and verifying data parts.

Your part of the project would involve implementing the bencode routines for tracker communication and communications protocols for client-to-client transfers, then tying it all together.

Comment: I very much doubt you'll be able to get this running on an AVR. The protocol may be simple, but the number of connections and state you need to track makes torrenting both CPU and memory demanding application.

Comment: I'd imagine that a single torrent could be downloaded *slowly* at least. You'd have to use a very small number of peers, probably 5 at most, but I think it could work. The BitTorrent protocol isn't actually *reqiured* to be intensive, as long as you're willing to put up with poor download performance.

Comment: If memory ends up being an issue, there's nothing to stop you hooking up an external RAM device to store some of the program state. It complicates things, and you may even have to hack together something with a shift register to reduce pin usage, but it would help solve the issue.

Comment: Oh, and it turns out there are I2C SRAM chips out there, which make external RAM a whole lot easier: http://arduino_related.livejournal.com/1414.html

Comment: Just as an update: I took this as a challenge and built one on an Arduino Mega. The Ethernet shield handles most of the network state for you, and I used external SRAM ICs for storing the torrent state. I used a Netduino as a crypto coprocessor so that I could compute the SHA1 block hashes asynchronously. The major limitation was seed count because you simply run out of processing power and memory to keep track of all the partial blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Almost anything that can run Linux can do this.  The [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) board is one of the new trendy ones.

There are lots more, but this question/answer would quickly degenerate into a [shopping](http://beagleboard.org/) project.  Google is your friend here.